# Format date in php from unknown format /Date(1576648800000)/

Tags: php

I'm calling the API and from getting the Date as `/Date(1576648800000)/` this format.

I don't know what the format is?

I want to convert it to `Y-m-d H:i:s` in php can anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: The number is timestamp in millisecond, equals to Wednesday, 18 December 2019 06:00:00 (GMT).

Comment: How can I parse the string `/Date(1576648800000)/` and convert as `Y-m-d H:i:s` this format? If I get `1576648800000` timestamp I can parse it. Thank you for your guidance. I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: It's probably from a JSON generated from the default C# MVC script serializer (maybe others too?). It was a Javascript trick where evaling the code would instantiate the date. Its pretty useless imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regex to extract the timestamp from the string.

```
$re = '/\((\d+)\)/m';
$str = '/Date(1576648800000)/';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $matches[1] / 1000);
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

which results:

```
2019-12-18 06:00:00
```

Comment: Can you explain little more extra `preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);` this line. The solution is perfectly worked for me. but suppose if I didn't get the same type of format will it work?

Comment: The Regular Expression (RegEx) matches the numbers (the `d+` pattern) between the parenthesis and extract into 1st match `$matches[1]`. I just changed to `preg_match` for simpler code.

Comment: Voted because it uses DateTime class.

Answer (score 2):

This is timestamp with miliseconds. you can change it to what you want. first you must remove miliseconds.

```
$time = 1576648800000;
$time = $time / 1000;
```

then you can change it with `date()` function:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time)
```

for get integer from string do this:

```
$dateString = '/Date(1576648800000)/';
$time = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $dateString );
```

Comment: Thanks, @ttrasn. I appreciate your answer. I know to parse timestamp. but I'm getting this `/Date(1576648800000)/` format. First of all I need to parse this string to timestamp and then I can convert it.

Comment: @DilipHirapara some APIs return string with timestamp. you must parse it with `substr` function.

Answer (score 1):

To get the time from `/Date(1576648800000)/`:

```
$string = '/Date(1576648800000)/';
$string = intval(substr($string, 6, -2)) / 1000;
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to filter the value. Since your format goes with  `/Date(some_number)/`, you can simply match the digits inside the bracket.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = '/Date(1576648800000)/';
if(preg_match('/\((\d+)\)/',$str,$matches) === 1){
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",intval($matches[1]) / 1000);
    echo $date;
}else{
    throw new Exception('Unexpected format received from the API');
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/cOCIq